# copy worksheet to another spreadsheet from my site

Tags: google-apps-script

The worksheet in question is a template.  It needs to be copied with formatting intact, so the API (which I've become more familiar with recently) seems to be useless for this purpose and is how I stumbled on google apps script.

I have a script that works fine if I type it into a browser.  Even though I put it in the browser and authorized it that first time, it apparently can't be run from ajax or iframes.  I need it to run silently as copying the template is part of a longer procedure and the browser can't navigate away to perform this task.

I was a noob to google apis a few months ago and cobbled enough together to get things working.  Now I'm a noob at google apps script and just don't have the time to learn all the fine points to get this one feature working.  Hopefully there's something simple I'm missing.  Any help would be extremely appreciated.

My Code.gs follows in case it helps:

```
function doGet(e) {
  var spreadsheetID = e.parameter.spreadsheetID;
  var templateID = e.parameter.templateID;
  var templateName = e.parameter.templateName;
  var spreadsheetName = e.parameter.spreadsheetName;
  var response = copyWorksheet(spreadsheetID, templateID, templateName, spreadsheetName);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(response);
}

function copyWorksheet(spreadsheetID, templateID, templateName, spreadsheetName){
  ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetID);
  ssTemplate = SpreadsheetApp.openById(templateID);
  wsTemplate = ssTemplate.getSheetByName(templateName);
  ws = wsTemplate.copyTo(ss);
  ws.setName(spreadsheetName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to use Google Apps Script with ajax or iframe [for security reasons](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=852#c3). The only thing you can do is [embed your script as gadget](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#embedding_your_web_app_in_google_sites), but this will only work if your site is made with Google Sites, not the other way around.

What I'd suggest you is that instead of using ajax, you just open a popup window which runs the script and notify them to close the window after it finishes loading, or even replace the last line of code in `doGet`, with this:

```
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<b>You can now close this window</b>');
```

This will appear as a message after the script has finished loading. For more info on HtmlSerive, [refer here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/).

Comment: Thanks for your insightful answer.  Since I've given the app access, it doesn't make sense to me that the permission I've already granted can't be used in an iframe (which is why I assumed it could be done).  Also, not sure how using Google Sites makes anything more secure.  The higher ups don't want to go with Google Sites and we can't have popups over and over all day so we abandoned the idea of formatting.  Out of curiosity, can it be run from a frame, rather than an iframe or is that still a security issue?